# ParameterizedTest no me funciona

Tags: java, junit, pruebas-unitarias

tengo que hacer unas pruebas y tengo el siguiente código y no importa que ponga no se ejecuta.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

public class test2 {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(ints = {-1, 5, 10})
    public void test(int argument) {
        assertTrue(argument > 0 && argument <= 5);
    }

}
```

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea bien aceptada por la comunidad es necesario que detalles el problema, ¿que quieres hacer? ¿como lo estas haciendo?¿cual es el error?, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)